# How to find contours around these objects in the colored images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]I have a problem where I need to find the contours around colored images. Currently I am able to get good results for some of the images but for the images with shadows I am not able to get good predictions. The algorithm also sometimes misses out some of the objects in the image. I need help with a robust algorithm which can help detect the contours in a correct way for varied images.[image]

This is another example -

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import cv2

from utils import getMaxContour, getFilteredLabelIndex

def get_image_dimensions(img):
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    return height,width

def create_blank_white_image(height, width):
    temp_img = np.zeros((width,height,3), np.uint8) 
    temp_img.fill(255)
    return temp_img

# Read image
inputImage = cv2.imread("new_test/images/5.png")
inputImage = cv2.resize(inputImage, (800, 800))
h,w,chn = inputImage.shape
ratio = inputImage.shape[0] / 800.0

# Create deep copy for results:
inputImageCopy = inputImage.copy()

width, height = get_image_dimensions(inputImage)
temp_img = create_blank_white_image(height, width) 

# Convert to float and divide by 255:
imgFloat = inputImage.astype(np.float) / 255.

# Calculate channel K:
kChannel = 1 - np.max(imgFloat, axis=2)

# Convert back to uint 8:
kChannel = (255*kChannel).astype(np.uint8)

_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Use a little bit of morphology to clean the mask:
# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 5
# Set morph operation iterations:
opIterations = 2
# Get the structuring element:
morphKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
# Perform closing:
binaryImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
cv2.imshow("binaryImage", binaryImage)

h_threshold,w_threshold = binaryImage.shape
area = h_threshold*w_threshold

(numLabels, labels, stats, centroids) = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(
    binaryImage, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
print("No of contours",len(stats))
filteredIdx = getFilteredLabelIndex(stats, areaHighLimit=area/2, heightUpperLimit=h_threshold*0.9, widthUpperLimit=w_threshold*0.9) # here we have to ensure that the height and the weight of the rectangle is neither to big or too small.

for i in filteredIdx:
  
    componentMask = (labels == i).astype("uint8") * 255
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    cv2.imshow("componentMask", componentMask)

    opIterations = 3
   
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
    #componentMask = cv2.dilate(componentMask, kernel, iterations=3)
    componentMask = cv2.morphologyEx(componentMask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

    cv2.imshow("componentMask", componentMask)

    cntrs = getMaxContour(componentMask)
    cv2.drawContours(inputImage, [cntrs], -1, (255, 0, 255), 4)
    cv2.imshow("contour", inputImage)     

    line_width = 4
    if int(temp_img.shape[0]/250)>line_width:
        line_width = int(temp_img.shape[0]/250)
    cv2.drawContours(temp_img, [cntrs], -1, (255,0,0),line_width )
    cv2.imshow("contour2", temp_img)

cv2.imshow("original contour", temp_img)
cv2.imwrite("new_test/my_algo_results/output/5.jpg", temp_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: *"The algorithm also sometimes misses out some of the objects"*, which algorithm? can you please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have provided it

Comment: if you can please provide the image that the algorithm didn't work well with it (before processing), so I can do the tests with it. Another point is: Why you don't just use [YOLO](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/12/yolo-object-detection-with-opencv/)?

Comment: I have provided the photos, I dont need bounding box thats why I didnt use yolo

Answer (score 0):

As Bilal says is better to be more concrete about the algorithm that you are implementing, but there are multiple methods to solve that kind of problem.

- If you have problems detecting borders because of shadows, you cantry to apply first a [Gaussian Filter](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1) to make the image loose details, making them more easy to distinguish interesting regions.
- If you want to use a new algorithm, personally i like the [Canny Edge Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) , because is so flexible drawing image edges based on gradient orientaton and setting the details that you need through maximum and minimum threshold